# ajax-loader.gif only visible on the target page but not on the starting page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to immediately darken the page background and display a loading icon on link click. The background is darkened correctly, but the loading icon is not displayed. I can't find the reason.

JS to add the class "loading" to the body tag on link click (onclick="addLoading()"):

```
function addLoading() {
    document.body.className += ' ' + 'loading';
};
```

CSS:

```
body {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
html, body { min-height: 100%; }
body.loading {
    background: #333 url('http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/images/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0;
    transition: background-color 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0;
    transition: opacity 0;
}
```

It works fine, only the ajax-loader.gif is not visible. There is just the dark background.

On the target page it works as it should (initially load the darkened background with loading icon and make the page content visible as soon as the loading of the page is finished):

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var removeLoading = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        body.className = body.className.replace(/loading/, '');
    }, 3000);
};
removeLoading();
```

CSS:

```
the same as above
```

Comment: Try once with `body.classList.add('loading')` and `body.classList.remove('loading')` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Your code works correctly. I just tried that. One question -- Does your screen has a scrollbar? If so, try scrolling down, and you'll see the loader. :)

Comment: Do you change the opacity? With an opacity of `0` you shouldn't see anything. And what about the `-webkit-transition: background-color 0;`? Anyway, the css for the background works fine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggYQae

Comment: It works just fine. Please check.

Comment: Winking fine. You can check it jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/xwow4dgL/

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Very strange, but suddenly it works. I suppose that it was some kind of caching issue. Clearing the cache did not help before. Sometimes I obviously do not understand the caching behavior.